# mssql convert(date) issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL Server 2014 French.

I would like to understand how I can convert to

1. Date,Date-time column to DD-MON-YYYY String[13-OCT-2017]
2. DD-MON-YYYY String[13-OCT-2017] to YYYYMMDD String[20171013]
3. DD-MON-YYYY String[13-OCT-2017] to date,date-time value

Usually in a mssql DB i would do:

```
select Upper(replace(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, COLUMN_NAME, 106), ' ', '-'))
```

However the above query fetches me something like:

```
31-AOÛT-2017 instead of 31-AUG-2017
```

& to convert from DD-MON-YYYY string to YYYYMMDD:

```
convert(date, Column_Name, 102),'-','')
```

which doesn't work in this DB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure why you want to do this? Can you explain your use case? The reason I ask is that the format of a date is a presentation layer issue, not a data store issue. If you are persisting dates to the store they should be "sent' in the form of parameters of the type date/datetime2 (or datetime for legacy) and not as strings. If you are retrieving date/datetime2 values then convert them to a string in the presentation layer (as late as possible in the call stack).

Comment: @Igor There are different objects created by different people requesting for input date in different formats. I agree that the design is not efficient however I really need to convert the date's to required format strings. Along with display, it also convert also affects the data-type of the output of a query. Eg when I mention string I mean char,varchar format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you let the client application that consumes a resultset format things according to the preferences set by the application. Why do you think you, the developer, should force the use of english rather than french (or any other language) month names?

But we know that you passed that decision point long ago. You can use the format function to do this. There is an example of **exactly this** in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

This is a language issue. Set the language for the transaction manually:

```
SET LANGUAGE= English
SELECT Upper(replace(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, COLUMN_NAME, 106), ' ', '-')) 
GO
```

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the comment but is there any way where I can do this without adding the SET LANGUAGE= English param and only with the Select statement.